# geom_line() does not plot points from a shapefile in its correct order

Tags: r, line, rgdal

I have been trying to load and plot a few shapefile in R using `ggplot()` and am facing an issue with a line vector shapefile. It seems that the `readOGR()` command is importing the line vectors ordering the points of the lines in the x-axis order so that the plot does not correspond to its correct shape. The "curvy" part of the lines are plotted wrongly, especially those in the right-most part of the plot.

The first figure attached illustrates how that shapefile is, plotted in QGIS. The second the output by loading the `.shp` with `readOGR()` and plotting it with `ggplot()`. I do so by running

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
areas <- readOGR('.', 'areas')
ggplot(fortify(areas)) + geom_line(aes(long, lat, group = group))
```

Any thoughts on how to fix it? Here the source [shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qr8uqa6tkkrwon/shapefile.zip?dl=0).

[image: plot in QGIS]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is how you plot the lines.
From the `geom_path`/`geom_line` help page:

> geom_path() connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data. geom_line() connects them in order of the variable on the x axis.

Therefore, you should use `geom_path` to plot the shapefile as it is:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
areas <- readOGR('.', 'areas')
ggplot(fortify(areas)) + geom_path(aes(long, lat, group = group))
```

giving:
[image]